# How to configure PayPal PHP SDK

Tags: php, paypal

I am making an eCommerce store with the PayPal PHP SDK and I am having difficulties configuring the SDK. In the [documentation](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php#usage), it says to use a dedicated config file you have to define the path of it with this line:

```
    define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', /path/to/your/sdk_config.ini);
```

I am confused about where I would put that line. Does it need to be in every class that uses the API, or just one central place?

P.S. I noticed in the samples that they used the alternative way of configuring the SDK; use a setConfig() method. However, I only found this used in the [sample/bootstrap.php](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php#L28) file in the repoisitory. So my question is the same: What would be the use-case of either of those two methods? I am probably missing what I am looking for in the SDK [repository](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/tree/master/sample), but I thought I would ask people who have done this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your `define` rule on top of your *eCommerce software* config file, it will be available to the Paypal SDK.

`define`d values are usually globally accessible by any file `includ`ing the original.

Comment: So I define the path in the config file itself, then all I have to do it include the file in any class it is used?

Comment: yes. include Paypal's define code in your eCommerce's software config file. what ecommerce platform are you using?

Comment: I am making it from scratch ;)

Comment: well i keep my fingers crossed :-)